# How to run Ansible tasks for each server separately

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory

I have an inventory file like below.

```
[all:vars]
ansible_user=root
zookeeper_new=true

[zookeepers]
10.16.0.31
10.16.0.32
```

Inside my *.yml* file where I have declared the tasks, ***I would like to run all of those tasks first in the server 31 and after that on server 32. Is that possible and if so, how can I do it?***

Currently, it runs single tasks on both the servers and then jump to the next task. As an example;

```
TASK [Zookeeper/Zookeeper-New : Stop and disable existing zookeeper service] ***
ok: [10.16.0.31]
ok: [10.16.0.32]

TASK [Zookeeper/Zookeeper-New : Find previous zookeeper version directories] ***
ok: [10.16.0.32]
ok: [10.16.0.31]
```

Instead, what I want is

```
TASK [Zookeeper/Zookeeper-New : Stop and disable existing zookeeper service] ***
ok: [10.16.0.31]

TASK [Zookeeper/Zookeeper-New : Find previous zookeeper version directories] ***
ok: [10.16.0.31]

TASK [Zookeeper/Zookeeper-New : Stop and disable existing zookeeper service] ***
ok: [10.16.0.32]

TASK [Zookeeper/Zookeeper-New : Find previous zookeeper version directories] ***
ok: [10.16.0.32]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think why you need to do that and if you can achieve your goals using the "normal" way.
If you really need to do it the way you describe, set `serial: 1` on your playbook. This will cause ansible to to one host after the other.

For example:

```yaml
---
- name: test play
  hosts: zookeepers
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - name: task one
      command: hostname
```

Check the docs for more info:

- [playbook strategies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html)
- [playbook keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords)
- [shows how to use
  serial](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size)

Comment: The reason why I need this is to run an upgrade for Zookeeper cluster. According to Zookeeper documentation, we should upgrade single server in a cluster and once it is completed, we should move to the next server. `serial` is a good option. But can I add a condition to _Play_ keywords? What I'm trying to achieve is, when only an upgrade is happening `serial` become to action and other time keep it silent.

Comment: I don't know of a method to add this on a condition. I'd suggest to put your code into a role and write a separate playbooks for install, update etc. which include the role and have the correct keywords for the thing you want to do. If you do not want to create a role, you can use the [include module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_module.html) to load tasks from another file.